# SQL Server 2008 transactional replication 'Missing end comment mark '*/''

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, comments, replication, transactional

I'm trying to set up transactional replication on a Dynamics NAV database on SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Using the same servers I have been able to set up replication successfully on a different DB.

I'm able to create the publication, subscription and the snapshot, but when I look in the event log I see the following error:

> *Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent [agent name] failed. Missing end comment mark '*/'.*

Replication isn't working, and the replication monitor effectively hangs when interrogating this DB.

A Google search returns this page: [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432461/snapshot-replication-missing-end-comment-mark-error) But I'm struggling to find where the system-generated stored procedure they refer to resides. I've tried hunting it down in the Profiler app with various filters, but not having much joy locating it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I have to say: Wow, what a stupid parser fail!  Way to go Microsoft!

Comment: Would you be able to try running the create script for all Programmability objects? It's a bit of a brutal method, but it would allow you to see if any of them fails.

Comment: From the connect item it looks as though the failure occurs when **you** have a stored procedure with `GO` inside a comment. I guess you can find it with `SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules where definition LIKE '%/*%GO%*/%'` then change the comment.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. This seems to have done the trick!

Comment: @Martin: Just stumbled across this, looks like you may want to promote your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that Martin's comment (also the most upvoted) solves the problem, as acknowledged by Loic. All credits due to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith).

> From the connect item it looks as though the failure occurs when you
>   have a stored procedure with GO inside a comment. I guess you can find
>   it with SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules where definition LIKE
>   '%/*%GO%*/%' then change the comment. – [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) Dec 13 '12 at
>   15:11
>
> Thanks, Martin. This seems to have done the trick! – [Loic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900873/loic) Dec 20 '12
>   at 8:56

Comment: This behavior is UNBELIEVABLE.  Still persists in SQL Server 2019.  Testing now to see if eliminating GO from comments solves the problem there.